# How is Excel's `RATE(nper, pmt, pv)` evaluated?

Tags: finance

I am trying to come up with the same answer as using the function `RATE`.  I've tried several formulas to no avail.

As an example, if I plug in `=RATE(60,94.36,-5300)`, it evaulates to $.00218$ .

The closest formula using the same time of inputs is the followin:

$i = (\frac{FV}{PV})^{1/n}-1$

where $n$ is the number of periods 
$FV$ is $94.36*60$ which evaluates to $5661.6$, and $PV$ is $5300$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be missing a sign.  I need to plug in  `=RATE(60,94.36,-5300)` to get `0.00218984`

This is essentially a special case of an IRR calculation, where there is a large amount at time $0$, followed by a number of a constant smaller amounts of the opposite sign. In this particular case it gives the solution to $\displaystyle -5300 + \sum_{n=1}^{60} \frac{94.36}{(1+i)^n}=0$, i.e. the solution to $\displaystyle \frac1i\left(1-\frac{1}{(1+i)^{60}}\right) = \frac{5300}{94.36}$

I doubt there is a closed form, but there will be reasonable approximations for small $i$. In particular, your suggestion should be approximately doubled to take into account that some of the payments are early and some late.

Comment: Yep, left out the negative on that.  I made the correction to the question.  Awarding answer for identifying what type of problem it is.  Thanks!